# Quick way SqlXml to XmlDocument in C# for a SQLCLR function?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, sqlclr

Which is better way to load `SqlXml` into `XmlDocument` (if any) without intermediate `string`?

I need to validate `xml` using `xsd` from database inside `CLR UDF`. I try to optimize my code.

My code is:

```
        schema1 = XmlSchema.Read(new StringReader(cXmlSchemaText), ValidateSchema);

        asset1.Schemas.Add(schema1);
        asset1.LoadXml(ValueString.ToString());
        asset1.Validate(ValidateXmlValue);
```

where `ValueString` is my `SqlXml`.

Comment: Just curious: why post this to S.O. when the 2 related questions are on DBA.SE? I would think this should also be on DBA.SE, especially with it being SQLCLR which only exists within the context of SQL Server. Or is this a better site for the C# aspect of the question?

Comment: You are right, but my problem is mainly C# related I decided that here I get more answers. If you can tranfer it to DBA.SE, @srutzky.

Comment: I don't know how to migrate, or even that it necessarily should. I was just wondering as there are many more SQLCLR questions here on S.O. than on DBA.SE, yet in my mind, that is something that should be on DBA.SE, but I could be wrong about that. It might just be my preference.

Comment: I ususally try to ask question connected with SQL in DBA.SE. I also wonder where to put this question (and you noted that I already have 2 more connected with this inside DBA.SE). I think here are more persons with experience in C# and will provide beter solution.

Comment: Ok. Again, I was just curious :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, even with `.ToString()` and `.Value` returning the same string value, it is probably best to use `ValueString.Value` for the sake of consistency in terms of accessing values within the `Sql*` types.

You should be able to skip the intermediate string by using the [SqlXml.CreateReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml.createreader.aspx) method which should, according to the documentation, be returning the internal XmlReader of the SqlXml variable. Your code would change very slightly to be:

```cs
asset1.Load(ValueString.CreateReader());
```